# shared object import error while cross compiling for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi3

I am cross compiling my files to put in raspberry pi. tool chain from raspberry pi official site was downloaded. Then cross compiled in my ubuntu 64 system using arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc. But when I tried to use these cross compiled .so file in raspberry pi it shows an error as follows :

error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How this error can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi is an old version, 
have you tried a newer cross compiler such as [arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf)